# internal tomcat inside spring boot application stops responding to calls

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, log4j2

we have a spring boot web application with tomcat. The application starts correctly and responds to requests but after some time the tomcat stops responding to requests, while the java process is active. All log4j related dependencies are added by following pom configuration

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>`

but i see the following error in console,

> Exception in thread "http-nio-8034-Acceptor-0"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/ThrowableProxy     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:555)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$PatternSerializer.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toText(PatternLayout.java:195)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.encode(PatternLayout.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:447)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
>     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
>     at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.log(Log4jLogger.java:376)   at
>   org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
>     at
>   org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
>     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)    at
>   java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)   at
>   java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:1042)   at
>   org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:181)   at
>   org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:147)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:481)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    ... 30 more

I monitored the VM's CPU, memory stats, everything looked fine. Not able to figure out why tomcat fails to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause for this issue. This a bug in spring related to how spring looks for static files.

The error in tomcat does not give us a clue but the same error occured in another VM but with some additional logs which said "too many open files" and that helped to find the cause.

[how can i handle with /tmp/jar_cache#######.tmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841072/how-can-i-handle-with-tmp-jar-cache-tmp)